# Technique and Model

Tags: neural-networks, terminology, model

What is the difference between technique and model?

Some say Linear Regression Model
Some say linear regression Technique

Do both of terms means the same?

Answer (score 2):

I think different people use these two terms differently. People from math / computer science background may say "model" more often, and people from engineering background may say "technique" more often.

According to wikipedia

> A computational model is a mathematical model in computational science that requires extensive computational resources to study the behavior of a complex system by computer simulation.
>
> A technique is a procedure to complete a task.

They do not have clear separation and different people may have different preference.